# How to SELECT and INSERT until ordered quantity is completed using nested query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

[image: Database Sample Picture]

Keeping in view the above picture I want to run my query until the `$orderQty` is met. In the picture the upper table is of `products` and the lower table is of `temp_salesee` which is  resulted after running my code.
Here is my code:

```
    $orderQty = 22;
    $trID     = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $proID    = 1;

$con->begin_transaction();
$stmt = $con->prepare("
INSERT INTO `temp_salesee` (
    SELECT
         null,
         $trID,
        `pid`,
        `pur_price`,
        (CASE
                WHEN qty_avbl <= $orderQty THEN qty_avbl
                WHEN qty_avbl >= $orderQty THEN $orderQty
                else 0
            END),
        `batch_number`
        FROM `products`
        WHERE `pid` = ?
        ORDER BY `batch_number` ASC
)
        ");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $proID);
$stmt->execute();
$con->commit();
```

In `temp_salesee` at 3rd row `qty` should be 2 so that totals `qty` would be equal to `$orderQty` at this point query should stop and 4th, 5th rows should not be inserted. And if the `$orderQty` is less than the `qty_avbl` as showing in 1st row of `products` table then only 1st row should be inserted in `temp_salesee` table having `qty` of 5.
thanks

Comment: Twenty equals two?

Comment: Dear @Strawberry 20 is ```qty_avbl``` in ```products``` table at row 3. While I am required to save only 2 in ```temp_salesee``` table at 3rd row, because it will be summed up in 15+5+ **2** which will be equal to the ```$orderQty```  ***hence I shall be able to sell 22 items of One product which is available in different batch_numbers.*** Please help me if my code approach is wrong then provide me yours (perhaps loop?). thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope and imagine that there must be a more performant solution, but anyway, consider the following:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_batches;

CREATE TABLE product_batches
(batch_number SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,product_id INT NOT NULL
,quantity_available INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO product_batches VALUES
( 1,1,15),
( 3,1, 5),
( 7,1,20),
(10,1,30),
(11,1,50);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT batch_number
     , product_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COALESCE(LAG(SUM(y.quantity_available),1) OVER (ORDER BY batch_number),0) running
         FROM product_batches x 
         JOIN product_batches y
           ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
          AND y.batch_number <= x.batch_number 
        GROUP 
           BY x.batch_number
      ) a 
  WHERE running <=22;
```

| batch_number | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fNhY2mjvujNQmvjvDnZKhC/0)

Edit:

Not tested extensively, but for older versions, I think you can do something like this (performance is probably terrible though), so seriously consider upgrading:

```
   SELECT x.*
        , z.total - SUM(y.quantity_available) running
     FROM product_batches x 
     JOIN product_batches y
       ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
      AND y.batch_number >= x.batch_number
     JOIN (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity_available) total FROM product_batches GROUP BY product_id) z
       ON z.product_id = x.product_id
    GROUP 
       BY x.batch_number
   HAVING running <= 22;
```

Edit 2:

Perhaps this is clearer:

```
SELECT x.*
        , GREATEST(SUM(y.quantity_available)-22,0) balance
     FROM product_batches x 
     JOIN product_batches y
       ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
      AND y.batch_number <= x.batch_number
    GROUP 
       BY x.batch_number
   HAVING balance < quantity_available
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DHED9dyxR2gMWaStyBZbN/0

Comment: ***I am facing error on my server version 5.7***     Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (ORDER BY batch_number),0) running FROM product_batches x ' at line 2

Comment: See edit above, but consider upgading to 8; it's a considerable step forward from 5.7.

Comment: Dear @Strawberry, I appreciate your effort but I am sorry it is not fulfilling my requirement. Actually, I'm developing a Medical Store application in which I require the loop ***query*** that should ```INSERT``` only those rows whom's ```SUM(qty_avbl)``` >=  ```$orderQty```. As in ```products``` table  ```SUM(qty_avbl)``` of 1st three rows is 40 (15+5+20). Now, 1st row of  qty=15  be inserted in ```temp_salesee``` table then ```$orderQty``` be 22-15=7 then 2nd row be inserted qty=5 and ```$orderQty``` be 7-5=2 and 3rd row be inserted with qty of 2 only. Plz edit my code or send me ur loop qry

Comment: There's no 'looping' necessary here

Comment: I am very glad :) that you helped me in solving my problem. Your suggested code in ***Edit 2*** is working 100% for me. In the code above I just changed ```HAVING balance < quantity_available``` to ```HAVING balance < quantity_available AND  product_id = $productID``` for different product to code work with. ***One last and final but little request is to add new column in the right side of ```balance``` namely ```qty_sold``` and its value should be resulted by subtracting ```balance``` from ```quantity_available```.*** and the work is done... I'm grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly, I'd just abandon the idea of using a "clever query" and use an ordinary programmed loop. *"Get 'er done."*  Prepare the `SELECT` and `INSERT` statement handles, begin a transaction, and run the `SELECT`.  Then, `INSERT` as many times as necessary.  Finally, `COMMIT`.

While there might be a "clever" way to do this after all, it just might not be worth finding.  And, it probably wouldn't be *obvious,* which might mean that it would be hard to maintain going forward as the requirements *(inevitably ...)* change.  So, I'd say, *"cut your losses."*

Comment: This is exactly what I told them before. They asked this question 5 times already.

Comment: hello,  as I was newbie on this great site but even I faced some problems, I am grateful to all specially grateful to @Strawberry who has resolved my problem with great enthusiasm. His suggested ***Edit 2*** code is 100% working fine for me.

Comment: hello @Strawberry , your suggested **Edit 2** code is working fine on low data (500 records) but is too slow on 8000 records or more. Any solution please to work with heavy data records...? thanks